# How to stabilize my table with width and lines in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tabular

I have some issues in this pretty simple table

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{I trial}
    \begin{tabu}{*{18}{X}[c]}
      V(mL) & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
      pH & 1.68 & 1.74 & 1.93 & 2.04 & 2.18 & 2.36 & 2.64 & 2.95 & 3.35 & 3.80 & 3.95 & 4.16 & 4.45 & 4.96 & 5.55 & 11.32 & 11.75 & 11.95 & 12.14 & 12.28 & 12.39//
    \end{tabu}
    \label{tab:part1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: We love to help. Could you please describe what the issue is? How do you want the table to look? It may seem obvious to you, but there are different solutions depending on your desired output. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Don't use tabu, this is more or less completely broken!

Comment: Can you add a [mre] and show a sketch how the result should look like? Just saying there are some issues is not very informative ...

Comment: @Dugnom I mean i just want a normal table with 18 columns and i want it to be clear but unfortunatelly i dont know how to make it , i am new at latex, can you please right down that code for me?

Comment: @farkhad Please add a compilable [mre] to your question so we can see your documentclass and packages. How to best squeeze such a huge table on a page will depend on the page geometry. If you don't show us the code, we can't know what would work for you.

Comment: @farkhad your columns are not 18! See my answer and comment it for any finer tuning :)

Answer (score 0):

The bad new is that your columns are not 18... the good one is that fixing that and using `landscape` pagination you can make it. Here's a suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,top=20mm,left=10mm,bottom=20mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{I trial}
\begin{tabular}{p{15mm}*{21}{@{}p{10mm}}}
\toprule
V(mL) & 0    & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    & 7    & 8    & 9    & 10   & 11   & 12   & 13   & 14   & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    &       &      \\
\midrule
pH    & 1.68 & 1.74 & 1.93 & 2.04 & 2.18 & 2.36 & 2.64 & 2.95 & 3.35 & 3.80 & 3.95 & 4.16 & 4.45 & 4.96 & 5.55 & 11.32 & 11.75 & 11.95 & 12.14 & 12.28 & 12.39\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:part1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output table]

Notice that, if your columns are more than declared, a linebreak is added automatically before the exceeding ones (like in your image).